# when it works CellEndEdit for DataGridView C#

Tags: c#

Can anyone help me to understand why events in data grid view did not work always in the same way?

**For example**

CellEndEdit sometimes work when press enter sometimes did not invoke CellEndEdit at all.

and once when I write DataGridView.Endedit(); it invoked the event CellEndEdit, I saw that because I debug the execution, next day I review the code also using debug but did not invoke at all, very strange for me?

CellEndEdit work when change the CurrentCell using mouse or rows also when change the Read-only property either for DataGridView on for the current Cell
I am now so confused and could not think anymore because what seems excellent and work very well, tomorrow work in another way in DataGridView and its event.

i have this code work perfectly when press enter or use arrows to end edit in cell

```
private bool AllRowCellsEntered(DataGridView dataGridView, int row)
    {
        bool allEntered = true;
        for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            if (dataGridView.Rows[row].Cells[i].Value != null)
            {
                int result;
                if (!(int.TryParse(dataGridView.Rows[row].Cells[i].Value.ToString(), out result)))
                {
                    allEntered = false;
                    // dataGridView.Rows[row].Cells[i].Value = "";
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                allEntered = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        return allEntered;
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        dataGridView1[0, 0].Value = 1;
        dataGridView1[0, 0].ReadOnly = true;
        dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[1, 0];

    }
    private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((dataGridView1.CurrentCell != null))
        {
            if ((dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value != null))
            {
                string _cellValue = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();
                int _parsedCellValue = 0;
                {
                    if (!(Int32.TryParse(_cellValue, out _parsedCellValue)))
                    {
                        dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = null;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        KeyEventArgs enterKeyDown = new KeyEventArgs(Keys.Enter);
                        dataGridView1_KeyDown(dataGridView1, enterKeyDown);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count == 10)
        {
            if (AllRowCellsEntered(dataGridView1, dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1))
            {
                dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
                dataGridView1.CurrentCell = null;
                MessageBox.Show("done!");
            }
        }

    }
    private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        int col = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
        int row = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            if (!(dataGridView1.RowCount == 10 && AllRowCellsEntered(dataGridView1, 9)))
            {
                bool allEntered = true;

                allEntered = AllRowCellsEntered(dataGridView1, row);
                if (allEntered)
                {
                    if (row == dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1)
                    {
                        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(1);
                        dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[0].Value = row + 1;
                        dataGridView1.Rows[row + 1].Cells[0].Value = row + 2;
                        dataGridView1.Rows[row].ReadOnly = true;
                        dataGridView1[0, row + 1].ReadOnly = true;
                        dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[row + 1].Cells[1];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[1, dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1];
                    }

                }
                else if (col == dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("you are in the last cell and not all values are entered,\n enter all values please!");
                }
                else
                {
                    dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[col + 1, row];
                }
            }
        }

   }
```

but there is a problem when i move between cellsin the same row using mouse.
so i tried to solve this problem like this

```
   protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if (keyData == Keys.Enter)
        {
            dataGridView1.EndEdit();// if i did not use it did not read the value of cuurent cell when calling AllRowCellsEntered method, here did not call the event dataGridView1_CellEndEdit may be because the property EditMode is EditOnEnter for DGV! 

            if (dataGridView1 != null &&
                dataGridView1.SelectedCells != null &&
                dataGridView1.CurrentCell != null)
            {

                if (!(dataGridView1.RowCount == 10 && AllRowCellsEntered(dataGridView1, 9)))
                {
                    bool allEntered = true;
                    int col = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
                    int row = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
                    //dataGridView1.EndEdit();
                    //check if all values in the current row are entered
                    //string ss = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();//here  error if the cell value is null
                    allEntered = AllRowCellsEntered(dataGridView1, row);
                    if (allEntered)
                    {
                        if (row == dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1)
                        {
                            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(1);
                            dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[0].Value = row + 1;
                            dataGridView1.Rows[row + 1].Cells[0].Value = row + 2;
                            dataGridView1.Rows[row].ReadOnly = true;
                            dataGridView1[0, row + 1].ReadOnly = true;
                            dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[row + 1].Cells[1];
                            return true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[1, dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1];
                            return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
                        }

                    }
                    else if (col == dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("you are in the last cell and not all values are entered,\n enter all values please!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[col + 1, row];
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
                }
            }

        }

        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
    private bool AllRowCellsEntered(DataGridView dataGridView, int row)
    {
        bool allEntered = true;
        for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            if (dataGridView.Rows[row].Cells[i].Value != null)
            {
                int result;
                if (!(int.TryParse(dataGridView.Rows[row].Cells[i].Value.ToString(), out result)))
                {
                    allEntered = false;
                    // dataGridView.Rows[row].Cells[i].Value = "";
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                allEntered = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        return allEntered;
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        dataGridView1[0, 0].Value = 1;
        dataGridView1[0, 0].ReadOnly = true;
        dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[1, 0];

    }
    private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

        if ((dataGridView1.CurrentCell != null))
        {
            if ((dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value != null))
            {
                string _cellValue = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();
                int _parsedCellValue = 0;
                {
                    if (!(Int32.TryParse(_cellValue, out _parsedCellValue)))
                    {
                        dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count == 10)
        {
            if (AllRowCellsEntered(dataGridView1, dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1))
            {
                dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
                dataGridView1.CurrentCell = null;// can move it but
                //dataGridView1.Enabled = false;
                MessageBox.Show("done!");
            }
        }

    }
```

ok, then i tried this with the property EditMode=EditOnKeystroke

```
        protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {

        if (keyData == Keys.Enter)
        {
           // dataGridView1.EndEdit();

            if (dataGridView1 != null &&
                dataGridView1.SelectedCells != null &&
                dataGridView1.CurrentCell != null)
               // && !dataGridView1.ReadOnly)
            {
                dataGridView1.EndEdit();
                //dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ReadOnly = true;
                //dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ReadOnly = false;

                if (!(dataGridView1.RowCount == 10 && AllRowCellsEntered(dataGridView1, 9)))
                {

                    bool allEntered = true;
                    int col = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
                    int row = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
                    //dataGridView1.EndEdit();
                    //check if all values in the current row are entered
                    allEntered = AllRowCellsEntered(dataGridView1, row);
                    if (allEntered)
                    {
                        if (row == dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1)
                        {
                            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(1);
                            dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[0].Value = row + 1;
                            dataGridView1.Rows[row + 1].Cells[0].Value = row + 2;
                            dataGridView1.Rows[row].ReadOnly = true;
                            dataGridView1[0, row + 1].ReadOnly = true;
                            dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[row + 1].Cells[1];
                            return true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[1, dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1];
                            return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
                        }

                    }
                    else if (col == dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("you are in the last cell and not all values are entered,\n enter all values please!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[col + 1, row];
                    }
                }
                else

                {
                    //dataGridView1.CurrentCell=null;
                }
            }

        }

        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
    private bool AllRowCellsEntered(DataGridView dataGridView, int row)
    {
        bool allEntered = true;
        for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            if (dataGridView.Rows[row].Cells[i].Value != null)
            {
                int result;
                if (!(int.TryParse(dataGridView.Rows[row].Cells[i].Value.ToString(), out result)))
                {
                    allEntered = false;
                    // dataGridView.Rows[row].Cells[i].Value = "";
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                allEntered = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        return allEntered;
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        dataGridView1[0, 0].Value = 1;
        dataGridView1[0, 0].ReadOnly = true;
        dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[1, 0];

    }
    private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

        if ((dataGridView1.CurrentCell != null))
        {
            if ((dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value != null))
            {
                string _cellValue = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();
                int _parsedCellValue = 0;
                {
                    if (!(Int32.TryParse(_cellValue, out _parsedCellValue)))
                    {
                        dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count == 10)
        {
            if (AllRowCellsEntered(dataGridView1, dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1))
            {
                dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
                dataGridView1.CurrentCell = null;
                MessageBox.Show("done!");
            }
        }

    }
```

I do not remember all variants that i have tried they are too much but every variant has its problems with dataview events!

so I thought if i can know if the end editing happens not because of using mouse, can i use sender to know what causing the end edit to happen?
may be that it will solve the problem

Comment: "I am now so confusing" Um. Yes, yes you are. Could you please phrase this more like a question rather than a wall-of-text rant?

Comment: @Areej show your code what is not working as you aspect.

Comment: I have shown my code , show me your answers not your wall-of-text rant?  @ Nyerguds

Answer (score 0):

ok there is tow ways 
the first is more save, but it need to press enter two times(and that i did not want) here it is :

```
        private bool AllRowCellsEntered(DataGridView dataGridView, int row)
    {
        bool allEntered = true;
        for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            if (dataGridView.Rows[row].Cells[i].Value != null)
            {
                int result;
                if (!(int.TryParse(dataGridView.Rows[row].Cells[i].Value.ToString(), out result)))
                {
                    allEntered = false;
                    // dataGridView.Rows[row].Cells[i].Value = "";
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                allEntered = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        return allEntered;
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        dataGridView1[0, 0].Value = 1;
        dataGridView1[0, 0].ReadOnly = true;
        dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[1, 0];

    }
    private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((dataGridView1.CurrentCell != null))
        {
            if ((dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value != null))
            {
                string _cellValue = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();
                int _parsedCellValue = 0;
                {
                    if (!(Int32.TryParse(_cellValue, out _parsedCellValue)))
                    {
                        dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count == 10)
        {
            if (AllRowCellsEntered(dataGridView1, dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1))
            {
                dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
                //dataGridView1.CurrentCell = null;
                MessageBox.Show("done!");

            }
        }

    }
    private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        {

            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                int col = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
                int row = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
                if (!(dataGridView1.RowCount == 10 && AllRowCellsEntered(dataGridView1, 9)))
                {
                    bool allEntered = true;

                    allEntered = AllRowCellsEntered(dataGridView1, row);
                    if (allEntered)
                    {
                        if (row == dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1)
                        {
                            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(1);
                            dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[0].Value = row + 1;
                            dataGridView1.Rows[row + 1].Cells[0].Value = row + 2;
                            dataGridView1.Rows[row].ReadOnly = true;
                            dataGridView1[0, row + 1].ReadOnly = true;
                            dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[row + 1].Cells[1];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[1, dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1];
                        }

                    }
                    else if (col == dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("you are in the last cell and not all values are entered,\n enter all values please!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[col + 1, row];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
   }
```

the second way to override the method ProcessCmdKey (that is not always save but here i have just datagridview in the interface so there is no problem i guess)

```
        bool _enter = false;
    private bool AllRowCellsEntered(DataGridView dataGridView, int row)
    {
        bool allEntered = true;
        for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            if (dataGridView.Rows[row].Cells[i].Value != null)
            {
                int result;
                if (!(int.TryParse(dataGridView.Rows[row].Cells[i].Value.ToString(), out result)))
                {
                    allEntered = false;
                    // dataGridView.Rows[row].Cells[i].Value = "";
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                allEntered = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        return allEntered;
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        dataGridView1[0, 0].Value = 1;
        dataGridView1[0, 0].ReadOnly = true;
        dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[1, 0];

    }
    private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((dataGridView1.CurrentCell != null))
        {
            if ((dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value != null))
            {
                string _cellValue = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();
                int _parsedCellValue = 0;
                {
                    if (!(Int32.TryParse(_cellValue, out _parsedCellValue)))
                    {
                        dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = null;
                    }
                    //else
                    //{
                    //    KeyEventArgs enterKeyDown = new KeyEventArgs(Keys.Enter);
                    //    //dataGridView1.EndEdit();

                    //    dataGridView1_KeyDown(dataGridView1, enterKeyDown);
                    //}
                    if (_enter)
                    {
                        KeyEventArgs enterKeyDown = new KeyEventArgs(Keys.Enter);
                        dataGridView1_KeyDown(dataGridView1, enterKeyDown);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count == 10)
        {
            if (AllRowCellsEntered(dataGridView1, dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1))
            {
                dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
                //dataGridView1.CurrentCell = null;
                MessageBox.Show("done!");

            }
        }

    }
    private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        //if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell != null)
        {

            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                int col = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
                int row = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
                if (!(dataGridView1.RowCount == 10 && AllRowCellsEntered(dataGridView1, 9)))
                {
                    bool allEntered = true;

                    allEntered = AllRowCellsEntered(dataGridView1, row);
                    if (allEntered)
                    {
                        if (row == dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1)
                        {
                            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(1);
                            dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[0].Value = row + 1;
                            dataGridView1.Rows[row + 1].Cells[0].Value = row + 2;
                            dataGridView1.Rows[row].ReadOnly = true;
                            dataGridView1[0, row + 1].ReadOnly = true;
                            dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[row + 1].Cells[1];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[1, dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1];
                        }

                    }
                    else if (col == dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("you are in the last cell and not all values are entered,\n enter all values please!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[col + 1, row];
                    }
                }
                _enter = false;
            }
        }
   }

    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if (!dataGridView1.ReadOnly)
        {
            if (keyData == Keys.Enter)
            {
                if (dataGridView1 != null &&
                    dataGridView1.SelectedCells != null &&
                    dataGridView1.CurrentCell != null)
                {
                    {
                        _enter = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
```

hope it helps!